# Sublattice symmetry and the Fermi level

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators, lattice-model, topological-phase

I am a math student who is learning topological phases from [this website](https://topocondmat.org/w1_topointro/0d.html).

Let's assume the fermi level is zero. For the graphene, the sublattice symmetry $\sigma_z H \sigma_z = -H$ makes the Hamiltonian look like

\begin{align*}
H = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & H_{AB}\\
H_{AB}^\dagger & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

I can see that the spectrum of $H$ is symmetric with respect to the fermi level, but I don't see why it is away from $0$. In my understanding, a Hamiltonian is a hermitian operator that may differ from questions to question. Therefore, for example, the trivial case $H_{AB} = 0$ clearly has $0$ in the spectrum; or when $H_{AB}$ has eigenvalue $0$, then so does $H$.

When physics people write down a Hamiltonian, is there any assumption or convention made without explicitly stated? For instance, $H_{AB}$ is assumed to be positive definite? Or the fact that the spectrum is away from $0$ is based on observation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When physics people write down a Hamiltonian, is there any assumption or convention made without explicitly stated? For instance, $H_{AB}$ is assumed to be positive definite?

There is no general assumption or convention. First, note that the page you link to provides an example of an $H_{AB}$ that is not positive definite,
$$
H_{AB}=\pmatrix{0.47+0.62I&0.65+1.46I\\1.98-0.03I&-0.71+1.76I}.
$$

Although there is no overall convention, it is often convenient to separately discuss the cases where $H$ is gapped and where $H$ is gapless. In many contexts, not least in discussions of topological states and invariants, the gapped case is more straight-forward, which is why it's often treated first. Some authors may find it convenient to consider gapped systems the default, but careful authors will specify whether a gap is present or absent. In the case of the resource you link to, the section on [Sublattice symmetry](https://topocondmat.org/w1_topointro/0d.html#sublattice-symmetry) follows the section on [Topology and **gapped** quantum systems](https://topocondmat.org/w1_topointro/0d.html#topology-and-gapped-quantum-systems), which indicates that the notion of topology used in the rest of the page concerns gapped systems. They discuss topology in gapless systems [elsewhere](https://topocondmat.org/w10_extensions/gapless.html), specifically treating the case where $\det H_{AB}=0$.